# namespace is use like a type using nest elasticclient

Tags: nest

I am using NEST to connect to the elasticsearch server:

```cs
var searchBoxUri = new Uri("xxx");
var elasticSettings = new ConnectionSettings(searchBoxUri).SetDefaultIndex("xxx");
var client = new ElasticClient(elasticSettings);
```

I got this error:

```
'ElasticClient' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```cs
var client = new Nest.ElasticClient(elasticSettings);
```

You should use full qualified class name.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I am using the same name for project namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
            private ElasticClient _Instance;

            var elasticSearchURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["elasticSearchURI"];

            var node = new Uri(elasticSearchURI);
            var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { node });

            var config = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool, defaultIndex)
                                    .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                                    .SniffOnStartup(false)
                                    .DisablePing();

            _Instance = new ElasticClient(config);
```

Where defaultIndex is a string with the name of the index .